# JavaScript not a function with promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Due to uncommon nature of the API I deal with I have stuck with strange Promise related issue in the JS. I have button fetching data from the API asynchronously and processing them.

Button Code

```
$("#hist-testu").on("click",function(){
 bbhistory_object=BBhistory();

 Promise.all([bbhistory_object]).then(function(result_array){
 //do some stuff
 })
})
```

I am having promise in button as there might be more subprocesses launched by the button which code will have to wait for.

BBHistory function:

```
function BBhistory(){
 return BBobject = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

  var fetch_1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    //do some async stuff
    resolve(some_strings);
   });

  var fetch_2 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    //do some async stuff
    resolve(some_strings);
   });

  Promise.all([fetch_1, fetch_2]).then(function(result_array){
    //do some stuff with results
    BBhistory = result;
    BBtransactions = result;
    BBobject={0:BBhistory,1:BBtransactions};
    resolve(BBobject);
  })

 })
}
```

So as you can see I fetch 2 results of API calls, and return them as an Object to main code / button response so I can used it in display phase.
Everything works great first time I click button. But on the second run I keep on getting **Uncaught Type Error: BBhistory is not a function** in the first line of button. I tried undefining/ clearing all variables involved but with no avail..

EDIT:
despite the great solutions and tips in the comments and in the answer, the real reason was that `BBhistory` variable was double-used in the `Promise.all()`. Changing that var to something else solved initial problem.

Comment: I suspect you're not showing the relevant part of the code. Are you sure you don't have a `BBhistory = ` somewhere else, similar to that horrible `return BBObject = ` ?

Comment: Are the 2 snippets in the same file?

Comment: In addition to Denys' comment above: 1. In `BBhistory`, it makes (with respect) no sense to store the promise you're returning in a variable, 2. And even less sense to overwrite that variable with a new value when resolving, 3. And even *less* sense to make that variable visible outside the function itself or possibly even global (you haven't shown anything declaring `BBobject`). 4. In the click handler, there's no reason to use `Promise.all` when you're only dealing with one promise.

Comment: @DenysSéguret you were right! that was a silly mistake I had BBhistory used as variable in the first async but assumed that if it's a different type it will work (duh!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why do you think I shouldn't store the promise result in variable? when I try to remove BBObject I have a resolve not defined error. And it's not global :) you already pointed this to me in another post AFAIR :D Point clicker will use more than one promise in the final solution.

Comment: @darth0s: I'm referring to the `BBobject` variable. It serves no purpose (as shown).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I was thinking about returning last promise directly but thought it will not work.. I will dig deeper and try the Bergur solution

Comment: But all of the above (and Bergur's answer) are tangential to the question. We can't tell you why `BBhistory` isn't defined/isn't a function, because the code above clearly *does* define it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this a lot. There's no need to make a promise function with a resolve and reject callback. The fetch function returns a promise and Promise.all returns a promise. So just return that promise instead of wrapping everything.

HTML

```
<button id="MyButton">Press Me</button>

<p>
String 1:
<span id="string1"></span>
</p>
<p>
String 2:
<span id="string2"></span>
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#MyButton").click(myClick);

function myClick() {
    BBhistory().then(function(arr) {
        $("#string1").text(arr[0]);    
        $("#string2").text(arr[1]);    

        // Do some other stuff with results
    });
};

function BBhistory() {

  var fetch_1 = Promise.resolve("some_strings 1");   
  var fetch_2 = Promise.resolve("some_strings 2");

  return Promise.all([fetch_1, fetch_2]);  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5h8ztho3/4/

Comment: While that's true, it doesn't answer the question. If the OP's getting *"`BBhistory` is not a function"*, just changing the contents of `BBhistory` and the click handler won't do anything to fix that.

Comment: Duly noted. I've updated the answer with full functionality....of what I think he is looking for.